# How does CGLIB proxy String or other final classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cglib

I would like to ask a question regarding Lazy Fetching in Hibernate.

As far as I know, in order to implement Lazy Fetching, Hibernate creates a placeholder that is a proxy of the real property.

What if my entity includes a String property or other final class? How will CGLIB subclass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling the long story short:

1. CGLib cannot proxy final classes at all, you might have seen previously in your logs something like `Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class SomeClass]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class`
2. Hibernate proxies your entity class at first, having corresponding [attribute Interceptors](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/bytecode/enhance/spi/interceptor/LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java#L36) injected into respective getters, so that actual call stack usually looks like the following:

> ```
> myEntity.getMyString()
>    |_ proxy.getMyString()
>      |_ lazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.fetchAttribute(myEntity,"myString")
>        |_ ... (actual call to underlying DB if required)
> ```

That is, everything you state here is correct:

> Hibernate creates a placeholder that is a proxy of the real ...

if you end this phrase with the word **entity**/**pojo** instead of property